# Symfony 4 table relationships do not work out of naming strategy?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, relationship

I have created two entities of existing database tables, these tables use the doctrine conventions for table relationships, I need to relate the tables to be able to work, the entities work by consulting data, but not between them.

Table name "Articulos"

```
class Articulos
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $ID_Articulo;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_Clasificacion_Articulo", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClasificacionesArticulos")
     */
    private $ID_Clasificacion_Articulo;
.......

Table name "ClasificacionesArticulos"
class ClasificacionesArticulos
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_Clasificacion_Articulo", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Articulos", mappedBy="ID_Clasificacion_Articulo")
     */
    private $ID_Clasificacion_Articulo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $Codigo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $Nombre;
.........
```

When I consult any of the entities, returns result without children of relationships. I suppose it's because of the names of the fields id does not use the name strategies, but I can not change them in the database, I have to adapt to it by requirements.

If someone has an idea, I thank you very much

Comment: could you please explain me why you have to use such an odd naming strategy?

Comment: @LuninRoman the database is of a system in production that they used many years ago and today. I have to use their tables. is a database developed in mssql

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by implementing custom Doctrine naming strategy. In Symfony entity, use camelCase to avoid any problems with naming. But, if you need specific table names follow [the guide](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/namingstrategy.html)

You have to implement `NamingStrategy` class:

```
class CustomNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategy
{
}
```

register it as a service by adding following to the end of the the config/services.yaml :

```
app.naming_strategy.custom:
    class: App\Service\CustomNamingStrategy
    autowire: true
```

Then specify naming strategy by editing config/packages/doctrine.yaml as follows:

```
naming_strategy: app.naming_strategy.custom
```

I believe you are looking for `propertyToColumnName` method, as Doctrine says

> If you have database naming standards, like all table names should be
>   prefixed by the application prefix, all column names should be lower
>   case, you can easily achieve such standards by implementing a naming
>   strategy.

Comment: My friend, then I'll tell you how it goes. I'm going to try it thank you so much for help me.

Comment: You linked to the guide but let's be honest, it's very sparse with information and doesn't explain what each thing does or how the inner workings uses each method.